# Ошибка при сравнении строк: no match for ‘operator!=’

Tags: строки, c++

```
std::vector<std::string> *get_playlist(int day) {

std::vector<std::string> *playlist;

ifstream playlist_file(get_path(day));

while (!playlist_file.eof())
{

    std::string str;

    std::getline(playlist_file, str);

    std::vector<std::string> temp = split(str, '.');
    std::string exe = temp[temp.size()-1];
    //delete temp;

    if (exe != std::string("mp4") || exe != std::string("avi")) continue;
    //delete exe;

    int vector_size = playlist->size();

    if (vector_size > 0) {
        bool is = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++) {
            if (playlist[i] != str) {
            } else {
                is = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!is) {
            playlist->push_back(str);
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
        }
        //delete is;
    } else {
        playlist->push_back(str);
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }

    //std::cout << str << std::endl;

    delete str;
}

return playlist;
}
```

Ошибка на эту строку if (playlist[i] != str) {  :

```
omxplayer.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >* get_playlist(int)’:  
omxplayer.cpp:220:36: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘*(playlist + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)i) * 12u))) != str’  
omxplayer.cpp:220:36: note: candidates are:  
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iosfwd:42:0,  
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:39,  
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/istream:40,  
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/fstream:40,  
                 from omxplayer.cpp:31:
```

Comment: правильно ругается str - это строка. а playlist[i]- указатель на строку. Думаю, что то вида

    playlist->at(i) != str

должно помочь.

Но я бы избавился от этого указателя.

Comment: @hitman249, Вы забыли сам вектор `playlist` создать (через ``new`), а `str` в конце удалять не надо.

Также, у Вас всегда новые строки будут добавляться в `playlist` из-за

      bool is = true;

в `else`. Надо написать просто

      is = true;

На мой вкус использование `split`, вектора для его результата (кстати, а что будет с именем, например, `avi` без всяких расширений?) и пары конструкторов `string` для целей поиска последнего компонента имени -- явный перебор.

И еще. Если `get_path(day)` это та самая реализация, о которой Вы спрашивали пару дней назад, то тут будет утечка памяти.

Comment: спасибо, я бы с радостью эту утечку ликвидировал, если бы мне ответили где:(  
там в топике добавил вариант который использую  
http://hashcode.ru/questions/323071/c-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: @hitman249: Смотрите, вот вам правило. Каждому `new` должен соответствовать `delete`. За этим приходится следить (в отличие от Питона, где ненужную память забирает garbage collector). Если функция `get_path` выделяет память при помощи `new`, то вызывающий код обязан эту память освободить. [Если я правильно понял замечание @avp.]

Comment: @hitman249: Угу, так и есть. Делайте так:

    char* path = get_path(day);

    { // этот блок ограничивает область жизни playlist_file
        ifstream playlist_file(path);
        // работа с файлом
        // ...
    }
    // здесь файл больше не нужен, playlist_file умер, можно освободить память
    delete[] path;

Comment: @hitman249: чтобы не возиться с ручным управлением памятью, перепишите функцию `get_path`, чтобы она возвращала `std::string`  (потери по эффективности при переходе на `std::string` ничтожны по сравнению с расходами на работу с файлом). Тогда код упростится:

    string path = get_path(day);
    ifstream playlist_file(path); // никакие блоки и контроль времени жизни не нужны

Comment: Точно. 

Причем достаточно будет изменить только тип результата `get_path()` с `char *` на `string` и вместо `new ...` использовать буфер размером `PATH_MAX` (из `limits.h`) в стеке и `snprintf()` для его заполнения.

При возврате этого буфера автоматически будет создан объект типа `string`, который при возврате уже из `get_playlist()` автоматически уничтожится.

--

Правда, надо заметить, что все такие игры делают ллюбую более-менее сложную программу скорее более запутанной (как это не парадоксально звучит (Керниган где-то упоминал об этом)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну да, `playlist` — это же не вектор, а указатель на вектор.

Попробуйте так:

```
(*playlist)[i] != str
```

---

Кстати, в старом C++ идиоматический метод возвращать массив из функции — это через ссылку:

```
void get_playlist(int day, std::vector<std::string>& playlist) {
```

Сейчас в тренде [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) и возвращение по значению:

```
std::vector<std::string> get_playlist(int day) {
```

(от лишнего копирования должен спасти умный оптимизирующий компилятор)